# How can you create an ADLS account using .NET APIs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

Can anyone share that to programmatically create an ADLS gen1 data lake in an Azure subscription using C# code (not powershell, az cli, etc)?

I've come across documentation like this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data-lake-store?view=azure-dotnet - this assumes the lake already exists

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk#create-a-data-lake-storage-gen1-account) for the detailed steps.

**Note**:

1.For the `account name`, do not use the suffix `.azuredatalakestore.net`

2.For Authentication, I use the [service-to-service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-net-sdk#service-to-service-authentication-with-client-secret). It will use TENANT_id(directory id in AAD),CLIENTID(application id in AAD), and secret_key, you can get them by following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

3.Install the following version packages as mentioned in official doc(you can use other versions, but need to make some small changes):

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store - This tutorial uses v2.1.3-preview.
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication - This tutorial uses v2.2.12.
```

**Sample code:**

```
    class Program
    {
        private static DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient _adlsClient;

        private static string _adlsAccountName;
        private static string _resourceGroupName;
        private static string _location;
        private static string _subId;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _adlsAccountName = "test333";
            _resourceGroupName = "ivanrg";
            _location = "East US 2";
            _subId = "xxxx";

            string TENANT = "xxxx";
            string CLIENTID = "xxxx";
            System.Uri ARM_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = new System.Uri(@"https://management.core.windows.net/");
            System.Uri ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = new System.Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");
            string secret_key = "xxxx";
            var armCreds = GetCreds_SPI_SecretKey(TENANT, ARM_TOKEN_AUDIENCE, CLIENTID, secret_key);

            // Create client objects and set the subscription ID
            _adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(armCreds) { SubscriptionId = _subId };

            // Create Data Lake Storage Gen1 account
            var adlsParameters = new DataLakeStoreAccount(location: _location);            

            _adlsClient.Account.Create(_resourceGroupName, _adlsAccountName, adlsParameters);

            Console.WriteLine("--completed--");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static ServiceClientCredentials GetCreds_SPI_SecretKey(string tenant, Uri tokenAudience, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;
            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(
             tenant,
             clientId,
             secretKey,
             serviceSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return creds;
        }            
    }
```

**Check the newly created account in azure portal:**

[image]